# Which value to take in order to get API data in the view?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Im connecting an API to a front-end app. In this case here I want to retrieve a list of users. I have written a service:

```
getList(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(`${this.url}/users`)
    .pipe(
      retry(2),
     // catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

and when calling in the page.ts:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllUsers(); // get the users wenn view intialize
    }

getAllUsers() {
    // Get saved List of Users
    this.userService.getList().subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
      // this.userList = response;
    });
  }
```

I get data when I'm looking in my network tab of the developer tool, that looks like that: `results: [{url: "url", id: 1, username: "UserOne"}]`

And my page.html I want to display this data with string interpolation

```
 <ion-list  class="pad" mode="ios">

          <ion-item lines="none" *ngFor="let user of (results | async)">
               <ion-label text-wrap>
                  <h2 class="title">{{user.username}}</h2>
                </ion-label>

              </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

Strangly I don't get an error and I can't tell whats wrong. Is that principally correct to call data to the view like that or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you mix up, `subscribe(..)` and the `async` pipe.

The `async` pipe is waiting for an Observable (ex: `this.userService.getList()`).

I can be used like this:

```
*ngFor="let user of userList$ | async)"
```

with

```
userList$: Observable<any[]>
this.userList$ = this.userService.getList();
```

Or if you chose to subscribe in your component:

```
userList:any[] = [];

this.userService.getList().subscribe(response => {
    this.userList = response;
});
```

with:

```
*ngFor="let user of userList"
```

Comment: I actually get with both versions this error: `Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

Comment: So your problem here is that response is not a list. You need to return a list.

Comment: But from the api I get a array as response. When I log my response I get this here: `results: (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`

Comment: The problem is not the problem of the list anymore. I suspect that you don't map correctly the result.

Comment: Both. I get it in both versions:/

Comment: Perhaps the array you want to iterate is contained into an attribute. You should check the structure of the received data. In your case, I suspect that you want: `this.userList = response.results`

Comment: Can I just append results to the response? Or do I have to define it?

Comment: just `this.userList = response.results` will be enough

Comment: The thing is that I get the error that results is not available for type "any[]"

Comment: change `this.http.get<any[]>` by `this.http.get<{results: any[]}>(`

Comment: Ok thanks Wandrille. It fixed it to that extent this error disappeared, replaced by a `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`. But I think I'll need to start a new question for that...